# Download file Activity refreshing while entering the activity each time

Tags: android, download, listactivity

I have a download book button in Activity A. when click on that it will move to Activity B where download list is there. The book downloading fine ( Async Using ). but while downloading if i came from B->A and A->B means the previous downloading file in download list in Activity B not showing. Android will kill activities while its not in focus.

I Want: go from B->A->B also, it has to show the downloading status in list. how to achieve this. This concept strucking me more.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You could try to download your data in a seperate thread. Like:

```
new Thread(
  new Runnable() {

    public void Run() {
      //your download process
      runOnUIthread(new Runnable() {
          //update your list adapter
    });
  }).start;
```

So it will not be killed until thread finishes its job. Also try to update your listview inside this thread.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply.... i am using AsyncTask to download. Can i update this procedure what you suggested in asyncTask also.? if running in separate thread means is it will show the listview with current downloading progress when we go back and reentered activity.?